# Minimum voltage of 18650

Tags: batteries

I have made a rechargeable torch using 4 LEDs in parralel and an 18650 battery. The battery is charged by using a TP4056 module. Due to the fact that I got 10 for 1 pound on ebay it does not have over discharge protection. What is the minimum voltage I can take the battery to. As the 4 LEDs wired in parallel are connected to a 100 ohm resistor will the LEDS switch off when the voltage is too low ?

Comment: "18650" is a size, not a battery chemistry.

Comment: But all 18650 battery's are Li-ion

Comment: Unless they're LiFePO4 or SLA.

Comment: Normally, you refer to the datasheet to find out the minimum voltage. Since you don't have a datasheet, use 3.5V as the minimum. Also, there are a lot of unbelievably cheap crappy lithium ion batteries out there. If you got 10 for a pound, chances are good that the batteries are complete junk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by 'Transistor' your battery will indeed be completely drained by the LED's, which is not a good thing. Since you took the battery out of a power bank that you got from Ebay, you don't have any information about it. So in advance, please excuse my 'simplistic' solution to your problem:

You could buy a ready made protection module from Ebay. Something like [this](https://www.ebay.nl/itm/BMS-Protection-PCB-Board-1S-2A-3-7V-for-18650-Li-ion-Lithium-LiPo-Battery-PCM/122651116182?hash=item1c8e938296:g:NfUAAOSwfcBZkrgQ) or [this](https://www.ebay.nl/itm/3pcs1S-3-7V-2-5A-PCB-BMS-Protection-Board-for-18650-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-CellW/283044583267?hash=item41e6c59763:g:rqEAAOSwBmpbOGn2) for instance. They look like this:

[image]

So it fits the shape of your battery. As you can read in the specs on Ebay (which might or might not be applicable for your specific battery) the cut-off voltage of those modules is somewhere around 2.45V - 2.55V. That works for a battery that is rated around 3.7V.

EDIT:
To be able to charge your batteries correctly, you'll need to know their *rated voltage*. Please be careful as you charge them, as charging them in the wrong way may damage them, set them on fire or make them explode...

Please be safe, those batteries can be dangerous!
Hope this helps.

Comment: You said the cut off was 2.5v, isn't that the cut off for an LED ?

Comment: The 2.45-2.55V volt I referred to was only about the battery. The cut-off of an LED depends on the type and color of LED that you're using. But they don't call that cut-off when you talk about LED's. I think what you mean is the *forward voltage*, or Vf. But that's a whole different topic...

Comment: My LEDs are the white unbranded ones from China available as 500 for £3

Comment: If the cut-off voltage of your battery *and* the Vf of your LED is the same, then that's a total coincidence. They don't have to be the same, but it's not bad if they are. It doesn't really matter. If you shared the information about your LED's because you have a question about them or about how Vf works, I'd suggest asking a fresh, new question on the website about it.

Comment: Do leds still take energy when they are not lit due to under voltage ?

Comment: This answer needs correction. 18650 batteries of lithium-ion chemistry can be safely charged usually up to 4.2V. Their nominal voltage is arund 3.6 to 3.7V. Please update your answer.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with my answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: Your answer is dangerous please correct it. When you say " I suggest you charge your battery, and check what voltage it gives you when fully charged." it seems to suggest you charge the battery like you would charge a lead battery and then let it settle, lead batteries can be over charged and then settle in to the battery voltage, lithium batteries will burn or blow up if you do that. To charge a lithium battery you have to know the max voltage. The other thing is that 3.7V is the nominal voltage but that's not the maximum voltage it's sorta the average voltage, only useful to calculate power.

Comment: @led42 Thank you for your comment. I edited my answer. Hope it is better now. Sorry it was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> I have made a rechargeable torch using 4 LEDs in parralel and an 18650 battery. The battery is charged by using a TP4056 module.

OK.

> Due to the fact that I got 10 for 1 pound on ebay it does not have over discharge protection.

I don't know why you mentioned the price or eBay. Those are irrelevant details.

> What is the minimum voltage I can take the battery to.

This should be specified in the battery datasheet.

> As the 4 LEDs wired in parallel are connected to a 100 ohm resistor will the LEDS switch off when the voltage is too low?

No. There is no switching element in your circuit. Current through the LEDs will fall but will continue to flow and discharge the battery.

Comment: I took the battery out of a power bank and there is no writing on it so how am I supposed to find a data sheet for it ?

Comment: @F.Ahmed, I don't know how you are supposed to find a data sheet. Do you know how anyone else is supposed to find a datasheet based on the information you have presented? I would say the minimum voltage should be somewhere around 3.5V. But without a datasheet, who knows.